# Generating a selection of dates from a given date to the current one, in equal three-month intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to get a selection of dates from the given to the current, breaking the range of dates into equal parts of 3 months. My code works, but it's clearly not perfect. Give advice on code refactoring.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

start_date = "2021-03-30"


def get_date_range(start_date):
    data_list = []
    now = datetime.now()
    sample = "%Y-%m-%d"
    first_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, sample)
    last_date = first_date + relativedelta(months=+3)
    if last_date < now:
        data_list.append([first_date.strftime(sample),
                          last_date.strftime(sample)])
    else:
        data_list.append([first_date.strftime(sample),
                         now.strftime(sample)])
        return data_list

    i = 0
    while 1:
        first_date = datetime.strptime(
            data_list[i][1], sample) + relativedelta(days=+1)
        last_date = first_date + relativedelta(months=+3)
        if last_date < now:
            data_list.append([first_date.strftime(sample),
                              last_date.strftime(sample)])
            i += 1
        else:
            data_list.append([first_date.strftime(sample),
                              now.strftime(sample)])
            break
    return data_list


data_list = get_date_range(start_date)
print(data_list)
```

Output:

```
[['2021-03-30', '2021-06-30'], ['2021-07-01', '2021-10-01'], ['2021-10-02', '2022-01-02'], ['2022-01-03', '2022-04-03'], ['2022-04-04', '2022-07-04'], ['2022-07-05', '2022-08-29']]
```

Comment: "Equal three-month intervals" is not exactly what you're doing. Since the end date is inclusive, these intervals are all three months plus a day. Are you sure that this is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel or use third party packages (dateutil) here. The `datetime` module already supplies you with a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object that you can apply to your datetimes to find the spans.

Answer (score 0):

`get_date_range` would be better-represented by a function that

- is a generator rather than constructing a list
- accepts start and end date objects, not strings
- does not bake in `now()`, for better testability and reusability
- generates tuples of start and end dates
- defines its input and output types according to PEP484

### Suggested

```
from datetime import date
from typing import Iterator

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def get_date_range(start_date: date, end_date: date) -> Iterator[tuple[date, date]]:
    while True:
        interval_end = start_date + relativedelta(months=3)
        if interval_end >= end_date:
            break
        yield start_date, interval_end
        start_date = interval_end + relativedelta(days=1)
    yield start_date, end_date


def test() -> None:
    for start, end in get_date_range(date(2021, 3, 30), date(2022, 8, 29)):
        print(f'{start.isoformat()} - {end.isoformat()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

### Output

```
2021-03-30 - 2021-06-30
2021-07-01 - 2021-10-01
2021-10-02 - 2022-01-02
2022-01-03 - 2022-04-03
2022-04-04 - 2022-07-04
2022-07-05 - 2022-08-29
```